# Enable sqlite3 FTS5 for PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, centos, full-text-search

I'm trying to use SQLite3 **FTS5** (full-text search) with **PHP** on CentOS.. but I couldn't get it successfully after so much time trying.

I'm building a loadable FTS5 Extension for SQlite and tried the following steps (from [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html))

in the server terminal (SSH) :

```
$ yum install libsqlite3x-devel
$ wget -c http://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/SQLite-trunk.tgz?uuid=trunk -O SQLite-trunk.tgz
$ tar -xzf SQLite-trunk.tgz
$ cd SQLite-trunk
$ ./configure && make fts5.c
$ gcc -g -fPIC -shared fts5.c -o fts5.so
```

But I'm having the following error in the last step:

```
fts5_index.c:732:11: error: ‘SQLITE_PREPARE_PERSISTENT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fts5_index.c:732:37: error: ‘SQLITE_PREPARE_NO_VTAB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fts5_main.c:888:29: error: ‘SQLITE_PREPARE_PERSISTENT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fts5_main.c:1029:31: error: ‘SQLITE_PREPARE_PERSISTENT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fts5_storage.c:139:15: error: ‘SQLITE_PREPARE_PERSISTENT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fts5_storage.c:140:41: error: ‘SQLITE_PREPARE_NO_VTAB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

The file `fts5.so` is not produced so I can't use it in the server

So do you have any idea how to fix this error and produce `fts5.so` file successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have to generate header files before the last step

so the full steps looks like this:

```
$ yum install libsqlite3x-devel
$ wget -c http://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/SQLite-trunk.tgz?uuid=trunk -O SQLite-trunk.tgz
$ tar -xzf SQLite-trunk.tgz
$ cd SQLite-trunk
$ ./configure
$ make fts5.c sqlite3.h sqlite3ext.h
$ gcc -g -fPIC -shared fts5.c -o fts5.so
```

Then I had to load the `fts5.so` as loadable extension for sqlite

1- Copy the `fts5.so` file to a new folder on server `/sqlite_ext`

```
$ mkdir /sqlite_ext
$ cp fts5.so /sqlite_ext
```

2- Edit `sqlite3.extension_dir` in `php.ini` to point to the same folder like this

```
sqlite3.extension_dir = "/sqlite_ext"
```

3- Then in my php file, load the extension :

```
$db->loadExtension('fts5.so');
```

---

## Update :

It's better to update server's SQLite as a whole with `--enable-fts5` option

```
$ wget -c https://www.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3280000.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf sqlite-autoconf-3280000.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3280000
$ ./configure --enable-fts5 --prefix=/usr --disable-static CFLAGS="-g -O2 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY=1 -DSQLITE_SECURE_DELETE=1 -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX"
$ make
$ make install
```

Now the latest SQLite is installed for the **server** but not for PHP, let's do it for **PHP**

```
$ mv aclocal.m4 config.m4
$ phpize
```

Check for your SQLite version in server using `$ sqlite3 --version` and in PHP using `phpinfo();`

*notice: the link mentioned in the first step is for the latest `sqlite-autoconf amalgamation` at the time of this answer. there maybe a more recent version for you . [check here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

[image]