# How to enable MATCH operator in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm newly in sqlite. I installed sqlite on my ubuntu machine. When I want to search in a table with `MATCH` operator I get the following error:

`Result: unable to use function MATCH in the requested context`

I also followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918643/enable-sqlite3-fts5-for-php), but it didn't work.

The question is: How can I enable using `MATCH` operator in sqlite for my ubuntu machine?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating a FTS table?  Which version of FTS are you targeting?  Are you using some other match plugin? How are you using the MATCH operator?

Comment: *"but it didn't work"* - Show your code. State the exact SQLite version, show your table definitions, give sample data and a sample SQL query, include the expected result. Linking to an external post is useless. The external post might go away at any time, and some random code from the other end of the Internet does not tell us what you did. Make your question complete.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard sqlite table you would need to implement the MATCH operator - see https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators

I've had a go at writing an extension that enables a match operator - the idea is to extract that part of a string caught by the regular expression.

However, you need to compile this yourself using gcc and g++. See https://github.com/njamescouk/matchExtension for more details.